# Is there an in-universe explanation for how eye transplanting works?

Tags: naruto

How can the characters in Naruto just have their eyes taken out nonchalantly, seemingly without pain and without regards for infection or damage? If I took out my eyeballs and put them back in, I can't guarantee that I would regain my eyesight. Shisui must've overdosed in painkillers.

Is there any in-universe explanation for how this works?

Comment: Because **Anime** and **Ninja**.

Comment: Because `Magic`

Comment: Comparing Ninja World(Anime) with real world is pointless.

Comment: I don't see how this is too broad. As someone who knows nothing at all about Naruto, I think it's reasonable to ask if there is any in-universe explanation for how this works, and I made some edits to make it explicit. The answer could be "There is no in-universe explanation, it just happens"—that's perfectly valid. It doesn't seem like a bad question to me.

Comment: Why the downvotes? I just want to know if there is a plausible explanation for it. Maybe it was mentioned somewhere in the manga or one of the episodes that I didn't catch on. Or it was implicit. Is that too much to ask to a site that is about helping others?

Comment: There is no in-universe reason. Ninjas have higher pain tolerance than most people and in anime, it's exponentially increased. Why? Because, it's fiction. Although I didn't downvote, I assume it's because of the preposterous nature of the question as the answer is obvious. Eye removals aren't the only disturbing thing that happens in the ninja world.

Comment: I removed the phrase, "or is it just one of those things that can only happen in anime?" so that it won't sound like comparison betwen RL and anime, which I suspect is why you got down-vote and close flags.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IIRC, the first eye transplantation ever shown in Naruto is when Kakashi got his Sharingan from dying Obito. At that time Rin was there to perform the transplantation and she was a medical ninja. Considering Obito's condition (he was crushed by a rock) I'd say that it doesn't hurt for him to have his eyes taken, because the damage he received would have made him numb to further pain. Was it hurts for Kakashi? Maybe. One thing for sure is that Rin was there to perform the surgery and being a medical ninja, she would've ensured that the transplantation is done as hygiene as possible. Kakashi was then shown to be able to use his newly transplanted eye possibly because **Rin used medical ninjutsu to heal the area around his eyes**, while also reconnecting the nerves to the eyeball using chakra. As mentioned during Sakura's training under Tsunade, **medical ninjutsu works by using chakra to control the regrow of cells**, thus healing the wounds.

The next one shown to have the eye transplantation was Uchiha Sasuke, but that was done in a hideout with Karin (a medical ninja) there. Karin is an experienced medical ninja, having worked under Orochimaru for years, thus doing something like Rin, and in a better environment should be easy for her.

And then we have Uzumaki Nagato. He got his Rinnegan from Uchiha Madara. Since Madara himself was the one who did the transplantation, and since Nagato is an Uzumaki, who is known to have a huge life-force, there should be no problem whatsoever with the transplantation.

Lastly, we also have the case where Black Zetsu took Rinnegan from Obito. Does it hurts? Yes, as seen from the pain Obito was in when Black Zetsu took the eye. Uchiha Madara then installed the eye, but with no help from other people and he just put the eyeball and puff, it's working like normal. The reason it is possible is that at that time Madara already have the Senju DNA, which enables him to have an accelerated healing, something that Tsunade noted to have been a trait of his late grandfather, Senju Hashirama, which is also the inspiration for her to develop medical ninjutsu in the first place.

So yeah, there is an in-universe explanation on how the eye transplantation works. Note that there is an inconsistency between Kakashi and Sasuke's case. Kakashi was able to use the eyes immediately but Sasuke wasn't able to despite being in a better condition.

Comment: Don't forget the time when Madara snatched out Kakashi's Mangekyou eye to use Kamui.

Comment: How about the time when Shisui lost his eye to Danzo and gave his other eye to Itachi?

Comment: When Shizui took out his eye it might not hurt badly because he is already in pain from having the other taken by Danzo. Itachi didn't transplant the eye into himself though. He use it as apart of the crow genjutsu.

Comment: @EroSennin same point as Madara taking Rinnegan from Obito, Senju DNA.

Comment: Sasuke got the EMS during his transplantation, so the delay before he was healed was due to that, while kakashi got a basic sharingan. Ninja are also quite tough, so indeed in some cases there is a bunch of pain, but they frequently deal with alot of pain in fights, so they have to be able to take it and be ready for another attack asap.

Answer (score 1):

When a ninja takes their eyeballs out, it's hurts. There's no pain killer or anything that stops it from hurting.

Like the fight between Sasuke and Itachi, Itachi used Genjutsu and took out Sasuke's eye, he screamed in pain. Afterwards he put it in a container with some sort of liquid that stops it from getting contaminated.

In an episode Sakura is learning healing jutsus, she healed a bunny with a broken leg and the bunny could run again straight after, she then healed an almost dead fish and it could swim again. Tsunade can revive herself by unlocking the diamond on her forehead, but shortens her lifespan.

These just shows how powerful healing jutsus are. If they can do that, they can definitely heal and transplant an eye. Even in modern life, there are eye transplant surgery.

Comment: The jutsu Itachi used on Sasuke was a genjutsu. He didn't take his eyes for real.

Comment: @AyaseEri yes i forgot to put that, but sasuke still screamed in pain when he took it out.

Comment: That pain is arguably from the jutsu itself instead of from taking the eyes out. Thus, it was a pain given by Itachi and not pain from the eyes being gouged out.

Comment: @AyaseEri it's arguable but i do agree